# Confused about editing the HTML in a template

Tags: templates, page-template

So I set up a child template off of 2023 WP 6.2.2 ....

I then added my own template (Template one) however the thing i'm not sure of is how to do is edit the HTML of the template...

So a few questions:

1. I don't see a new HTML file when I create a new template... not sure if this is how it is supposed to happen.
2. The Main div has the `"class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top: var( --wp--preset--spacing--50 );"` not sure in my new template how to get rid of the style part... I don't want or need it.

[image: The Directory Structure]

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/416359/edit) and tell us how you added a new template. Template files in a theme are PHP files, not HTML, so you *might* be looking for something along the line of `template-one.php`.

Comment: @PatJ In full site editing themes templates are HTML files.

Comment: @PatJ so here is my structure and the templates I created in the bottom image...

Comment: @JacobPeattie Huh, I didn't realize that.